# install qgis on debian jessie

Tags: python, qgis

I need to install qgis, qgis server, and lizmap on Debian jessie, and I can not install them. Currently my sources.list is as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48W3h.jpg)

debian version installed:

```
root@SIG:~# cat /etc/debian_version
stretch/sid
```

Firstly, the system was wheezy (7.3) According to our needs, I must make the upgrade the server to jessie.

here is my screen snapshot when I type on putty:

```
root@SIG:~# apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I  receive the following error messages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moDGm.jpg)

And I followed to apt-get -f install but the problem still resists.

I do not know; is it possible of the internet connection a bit slow? Because our internet connection is not famous

Desolated, we used the French language in our system

Comment: Don't post *pictures* of text.  Just include the actual text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're missing some dependencies. Try the following using root mode, or sudo if you wish.

```
apt-get install -f
```

then,

```
apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```